# Making a nested for-loop efficient in python

Tags: python

How can I make this program more efficient?

```
    tempPossiblePairs = defaultdict(lambda: set([]))

    for w1 in words:
        for w2 in words:
            if(w1 != w2):
                tempPossiblePairs[w1].add(w2)

    for w1 in words:
        for w2 in words:

            if(w1 != w2 and (w2 in tempPossiblePairs[w1])):
                res.append((self.getPMI(w1, w2), self.pair(w1, w2)[0], self.pair(w1, w2)[1]))
```

I wrote a program that generates (given a list 'words') a dictionary that takes a word as a key and words that can be paired with the key as values. Then I look through the words list again and see if they are not equal and they can be pair-able (by checking the tempPossiblePairs dict).

I know this code is messay and inefficient, but I would like to hear some tips to make this more efficient.

Comment: I don't see the need for `tempPossiblePairs`

Comment: Then how would I efficiently check if the w2 is a value of the key w1?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can boil this down to

```
from itertools import product

res = [(self.getPMI(w1, w2), *self.pair(w1, w2)) for w1, w2 in product(words, repeat=2) if w1 != w2]
```

The `*self.pair` bit is unpacking the result of `pair` into the tuple (This is assuming `pair` returns something with only two elelments), and I think it requires you to have a relatively recent version of Python 3

Comment: I got halfway through my answer before realizing that it's identical to yours.

Comment: this itertools a standard python package?

Comment: @Dawn17 yup.  You can read more about [`itertools.product` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: @Dawn17 if you don't want reflections (That is, both `(A, B)` and `(B, A)`), [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is probably faster